# Advantage of XmlTextReader over XmlReader

Tags: xml

What I see as a difference between XmlReader and XmlTextReader is that: 
XmlReader.Create allows you to specify XmlReaderSettings, which none of the XmlTextReader constructor overloads do. Also working with XMLTextReader means  Your code contains an extra layer over the root class of XMLReader.

Then why XmlTextReader came into picture? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

`XmlTextReader` is old. It was introduced in .NET 1.0. The `XmlReader` type was just a base class.

They added the static `XmlReader.Create` method in .NET 2.0. Since .NET 2.0, `new XmlTextReader()` has been deprecated.

Comment: Are you sure, XmlTextReader is old & deprecated as well? I guess following link does not suggest so: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx . It says that XmlTextReader is derived from XmlReader and is still supported in .NET Framework#4.5.

Comment: Yes. See the "Remarks": "In the .NET Framework 2.0 release, the recommended practice is to create XmlReader instances using the XmlReader.Create method."

Comment: Note that it is more than just deprecated... if you use 'new XmlTextReader' then it is put into "v1compat" mode which can result in massive memory usage (rather than proper streaming).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940927/why-is-my-new-xmltextreaderstream-reading-in-many-megabytes-into-memory-rather for more on that.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to customize

**xmlNodeName**

as some unexpected name, XmlTextReader comes into the picture.

```
<data:custome name='devtech' />
```